# How to get http content-length before loading document in jsoup

Tags: web-scraping, jsoup

I am doing some web-scraping using jsoup in java in a breadth-first manner. In other words, for each page, I extract all links and add them to a queue for scraping, then I deqeue and scrape the urls in a while loop, stopping when the queue is empty. What I want to do is sort the links by size of target document before they are added to the frontier/queue for scraping, such that the smaller documents are scraped first.  Is there a way to get the size of a given document from url before actually downloading the whole document?  Is there for example a way to get http Content-length from a connection before calling the connection.get() to load the whole document?  thanks.

Comment: Might be able to use HTTP HEAD requests to get the content length without fetching the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use http HEAD method to get a content length, without downloading a body of request. 
With jsoup this might look like this:

```
Response resp = Jsoup.connect(url).method(Method.HEAD).execute();
String length = resp.header("Content-Length");
```

More about http HEAD method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD